# An error occured when reading lines by readlines() method

Tags: python, csv, file-io

The following function is defined to read the content of the .csv file and store it into lists:

```
def _read_txt_file(self):
    self.img_paths = []
    self.labels = []
    with open(self.txt_file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            items = line.split(',')  # .csv
            self.img_paths.append(items[0])
            self.labels.append(int(items[1]))
```

Something wrong has happened in line 6. The PyCharm debugger shows normal values of variable `lines`, i.e. `'../ZP_45151/0.bin,0\n'`, `'../ZP_45151/0.bin,1\n'` and so forth. But the `line` variable displays a weird value, that is, `',\n'`, which is obviously that something has been lost. Does anyone have an idea that why the operation is not going through the complete content?

Comment: Are you *really* sure none of your lines are missing data? If you've got a few thousand lines, it can be easy to miss one. Side-note: You don't need `readlines` here. Just do `for line in f:` and remove the `lines = f.readlines()` and you'll process lines one by one without holding *all* of them in an in memory `list` up front, saving memory. Or even better, wrap it with [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), because `str.split(',')` is *not* parsing CSV.

Comment: Oh yes, some missing data exist in my lines. And thank u for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked my reading .csv file and found that there are plenty of blank lines expressed as `',\n'` in string format. The issue has been settled.